# Show details when mouseover item with determined class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a block of details that only will be displayed when cursor is on an item of the list, if the item has the class 'hasDetails'. I tried using 'mouseover' and 'mouseenter' but neither worked. I can't figure why this is not working. Could anyone help?

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#list').find('.listItem').mouseover(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('hasDetails')) {
                $('#details').css("display", "table");
            };
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
    <div id="details">
        <p>Details</p>
    </div>

    <ul id="list">
        <li class="listItem hasDetails">
            <p>ITEM</p>
        </li>
        <li class="listItem">
            <p>ITEM</p>
        </li>
        <li class="listItem hasDetails">
            <p>ITEM</p>
        </li>
        <li class="listItem">
            <p>ITEM</p>
        </li>
        <li class="listItem">
            <p>ITEM</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
    .details{
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your CSS is `#details` or `.details`? or I assumed you've fix your problem already

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#list').find('.listItem').mouseover(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('hasDetails')) {
                $('#details').show();
            };
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:
    `$('#details').css("display", "table");`

You are targeting an Id when it's a class ;)

Comment: actually i wrote it down wrong in my question, sorry